# How to manage newly created objects without "saving" before transitioning to a new route it in emberjs?

Tags: forms, ember.js, persistence

I have an issue where I have a resource with a new route. When I transition to that new route I create a new object. On the form I have button to cancel, which removes that object. However, if I click a link on my navigation, say going back to the resource index, that object is there with whatever I put in the form. What's the best way of managing creating objects then moving away from the form?

My routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('recipes', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', { path: '/:recipe_id' });
  });

  this.resource('styles');
});

App.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Recipe.createRecord({
      title: '',
      description: '',
      instructions: ''
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('styles', App.Style.find());
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

My controller for the new route:

```
App.RecipesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  create: function() {
    this.content.validate()
    if(this.content.get('isValid')) {
      this.transitionToRoute('recipes.show', this.content);
    }
  },

  cancel: function() {
    this.content.deleteRecord();
    this.transitionToRoute('recipes.index');
  },

  buttonTitle: 'Add Recipe'
});
```

I'm using version 1.0.0.rc.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code that you place in the `deactivate` method of your route will get executed every time you leave that route. The following code will delete the new model if the user hasn't explicitly saved it.

```
App.RecipesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    // ...

    deactivate: function() {
        var controller = this.controllerFor('recipes.new');
        var content = controller.get('content');
        if (content && content.get('isNew') && !content.get('isSaving'))
            content.deleteRecord();
    },

    // ...
});
```

As an added bonus, you now don't need to explicitly delete the record when the user presses the cancel button.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Here's a link to the documentation http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate just in case anyone was curious about deactivate.